# How to take screenshot of the Here Map loaded android screen?

Tags: android, screenshot, here-api

I am using Here Map in half section of the screen. Now i have added one screenshot button on same activity which will take screenshot of this screen. 
In output screenshot, there is a blank section where the Here Map loads.

So, How can i take the screenshot of Here Map section?
It's fine if i can take screenshot of only Here Map as we can do using google map.

It will be great if there are some examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the screen capture API. Please see these links for [MapView](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapview.html#topic-apiref__getscreencapture-onscreencapturelistener) and [MapFragment](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapfragment.html#topic-apiref__getscreencapture-onscreencapturelistener). It will capture a screenshot and return asynchronously to your code.

Comment: Thanks... is there any example regarding the same?

Comment: I gone through above repository but could not find example regarding screenshot.